# Map java Enum to Kotlin data class

Tags: java, kotlin, enums

I am making a call from service A which is in Kotlin to service B which is in Java. It return me an object which contains multiple fields. One of the fields returned in the Java object is an enum. In my kotlin code I have defined a DTO which maps the returned response to kotlin. I need to map this enum to a string value in kotlin.

DTO in Java:

```
public class PersonDTO
{
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private CountryCode countryCode;
}
```

The CountryCode is an enum.

Data class in Kotlin:

```
data class PersonDTO(
val id: Long? = null,
val name: String? = null,
val countryCode: String? = null //How to map the enum to string here..???
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Kotlin has enums too, just import it in your Kotlin code

Comment: The thing is I need to map the enum field in the response coming in to a ```String``` type in kotlin. Just edited my question. Sorry.

Comment: Use `.name()` on enum.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to the edited questio**n: How to map a Java enum to a String?

you can call `name()` or `toString()` on an enum to get a String representation of it.

`name()` cannot be overwritten and always returns the textual representation of the value defined in the code, while `toString()` can be overwritten, so it might be depending on your use case what to use. Because of the fact that `name()` cannot be overwritten I prefer to always use `name()` wich can have less side effects or unexpected behavior when working with libraries which are not under your control.

**Original Answer:**

1 you don't have to do this. You can use the same Java class also in Kotlin code.

2 You could just reuse the enum, like in option 1) you can reuse the Java enum in Kotlin code:

```
data class PersonDTO(
    val id: Long? = null,
    val name: String? = null,
    val countryCode: CountryCode
)
```

3 You can write a Kotlin enum with a mapping function to create the matching instance of the enum:

```
enum class KotlinCountryCode {
    EXAMPLE;

    fun fromJavaCountryCode(input: CountryCode): KotlinCountryCode? {
        if (input.name() == EXAMPLE.name) {
            return EXAMPLE
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. please see the updated question. Its a ```String``` field in kotlin but the response coming in is enum.

Comment: To the downvoter: please seee my updated answer. please explain your downvote so I could understand your opinion and improve my answer.